# A synonym for "go online"

Tags: synonyms

What synonyms are there for telling someone to "*go online* and search for it"?

Is there something like *go live* or similar?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the objective of going online is to search, I'd probably just tell somebody to *[google it.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_%28verb%29)*

Comment: Nice !! Appreciate !!

Answer (score 2):

'Look for it on the internet', perhaps.

Comment: On the Internet, or *in* the Internet?

Answer (score 1):

"Connect to the internet" would work. Or if they're already connected but don't have a browser open, "Open your [web] browser and..." or "In your [web] browser, ...".

Or you could say "search for it online."